# Thymeleaf page is not redirecting to another page

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using `Spring-boot` and  `thymeleaf` and I'm trying to create a registration page but I can't seem to get to `register.html` from my login page

From the controller I have the following

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = {GET})
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("/login");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = GET)
    public ModelAndView register() {
        System.out.println("register");
        return new ModelAndView("register").addObject(new User());
    }
```

For my login page I have this and it renders properly without an issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Log in</title>
        <meta
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
                name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../static/style/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../static/style/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/ionicons/ionicons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/adminlte/AdminLTE.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/skins/skin-yellow.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition login-page">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-logo">
                <a href="login.html"><b>Login</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="login-box-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in</p>
                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                               name="username"> <span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                               name="password"> <span
                            class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"
                                    style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Sign In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        <a th:href="@{/register}">Sign Up</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        <a th:href="@{/forgotPassword}">I forgot my password</a><br>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.error != null}">
                <div id="error">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                            <button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;
                            </button>
                            <h4>
                                <i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i>Login Failed!
                            </h4>
                            You have entered incorrect credentials please try again
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../static/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/adminlte/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I said, it's working fine

For my register page I have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Registration Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../static/style/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../static/style/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/ionicons/ionicons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/adminlte/AdminLTE.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/skins/skin-yellow.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition register-page">
        <div class="register-box">
            <div class="register-logo">
                <a href="register.html"><b>Registration</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                    <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
                    <form th:object="user" method="get">
                        <p>Show something</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../static/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/adminlte/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on `<a th:href="@{/register}">Sign Up</a>` in my login page, it seems that the page only refreshes and isn't going to the register page, as you can see I tried printing something in the `register()` method of the `LoginContoller` but even this isn't printing which tells me my method is never hit, on closer inspection in the browser devtools, I saw that the `register` page is returning a `302` status as seen in the picture

[image: 302]

I tried using a `String` return type in the controller but that doesn't work either.
I also tried to get the page without any objects being sent to it but that doesn't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You probably don't have your `/register` path set as `permitAll()` in your security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in my `SecurityConfig` I referenced the wrong page name

```
               .antMatchers(
                        "/static/**",
                        "/forgot/*",
                        "/actuator/*",
                        "/register")//this was wrong
```